# Reset Passwords of LDAP-Users at the first login

Tags: openldap, password, reset, ldif

I have an LDAP Installation running on an Centos7 system.

I want to create a big number of users. Those users will get a default password, so I want them to change the password at the (only)first login.

Is there an Option, which I could set in an ldif-file to enable this functionality? (Just on the first login not every time they login)

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Also, sry if Im asking that baldly, but was is an overlay insert in this cause, and for what is it needed? I inserted the ppolicy schema via `sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif` 
And created a passwordpolicy.ldif

**Edit2:**

So I  tried the solution which was mentioned here, but it seems something went wrong, it is just ignoring my command. I added the schema of the ppolicy schema.

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
```

Afterwards I activated the module by adding the following Ldif

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy.la
```

Than I created an overlay as found in some guides:

```
database: bdb
suffix: "dc=example,dc=com"

overlay: ppolicy
ppolicy_default: "cn=default,ou=policies,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Afterwards I added the accual policy :

```
# Creates a Policies OU (Organizational Unit)
dn: ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Policies
# Creates a Policy object in Policies OU (Organizational Unit)
dn: cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
cn: default
pwdAttribute: 2.5.4.35
pwdMaxAge: 3888000
pwdExpireWarning: 604800
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 300
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
#pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

Then I tried to add a user with the follwing attribute (user.ldif):

```
dn: uid=pwresettest,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: pwresettest
sn: andsoon
userPassword: passwort
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1005
gidNumber: 1005
homeDirectory: /home/pwresettest
pwdReset: TRUE
```

But when I log in with this user, there is no prompt to reset the password.

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

most sincerely

Twinhand

Comment: I would recommend to start a new question when the edit is so radical, if not you run the risk people overlook it.

Comment: Before testing your setup with an application, test is with command line tools: `ldapwhoami -x -h ldap://your-server -D uid=pwresettest,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com -E ppolicy -w`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your server is OpenLDAP.

If you deploy the [ppolicy](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1190.html), you get the option to force password change at first logon with the combination of `pwdMustChange` in the policy file plus `pwdReset` on the entry.

The upside is you are going to deploy something you are going to need in the future: password expire, password force check and so on.

The downside is ppolicy setup require: a schema insert, a overlay insert and a setup policy (a special entry to store your configurations).

The other problem is that while ppolicy is a general solution as it is placed in the directory itself, you could run in trouble to let it interoperate with you client tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The downsides , do not sound very funny. Is there also a solution without those downsides?

Comment: Also, sry if Im asking that baldly, but was is an overlay insert in this cause, and for what is it needed?

Comment: An overlay add capabilities to a database. With the ppolicy overlay you enable in a database the ppolicy features.